# Jquery masked Input v1.4 issue with Samsung Android device

Tags: android, jquery, html, input, jquery-mask

I'm facing an issue with jquery-masked-input v1.4 plugin.

I have a input field:

```
<input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="(999) 999-9999" />
```

and have applied the mask to it:

```
<script>
        $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
    </script>
```

It works perfectly on all devices ranging from desktops, mobiles (all iphones, androids) except for Samsung Android Devices.

What it does on these devices is when I try entering the numbers, it would enter only one digit and immediately the text keypad would open. Then when I try entering the numbers again, it would not show properly. Eg.

**I want to enter : (989) 942-0827
What I get : (898) ___-__9**

and the text-keypad keep opening up while I try to enter the numbers.

Please suggest any workaround. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I'm haven't the same issue. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Hi, me too facing the same issue, did you find any workaround for this?

Comment: Change type to `tel`

Answer (score 2):

This is very old, but thought I would post anyway...

Im not 100% sure I understand your issue, but try changing the type to number. This should force the number pad at all times, and not show the text keyboard

```
<input type="number" id="phone" placeholder="(999) 999-9999" />
```